# Countdown clock timer in Javascript for Flash Canvas HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, createjs

Working on a simple countdown in javascript (createJS) for Flash Canvas HTML5, and I'm getting the following error:

```
file_Canvas.js:318 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dtxt_days' of undefined
```

The error is specific to the line `this.mc_counter.dtxt_days.text = days;` and the 3 below that.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the js:

```
this.mc_counter.dtxt_days.text = "";
this.mc_counter.dtxt_hours.text = "";
this.mc_counter.dtxt_mins.text = "";
this.mc_counter.dtxt_secs.text = "";

var end = new Date('10/19/2015 10:1 AM');

var _second = 1000;
var _minute = _second * 60;
var _hour = _minute * 60;
var _day = _hour * 24;
var timer;

function showRemaining() {
    var now = new Date();
    var distance = end - now;
    
    this.days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
    this.hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
    this.minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
    this.seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

    this.mc_counter.dtxt_days.text = days;
    this.mc_counter.dtxt_hours.text = hours;
    this.mc_counter.dtxt_mins.text = minutes;
    this.mc_counter.dtxt_secs.text = seconds;
}

    
timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);

console.log(timer);
```

Comment: can u paste all code to somewhere.

Comment: check the dtxt_days if set correctly.

Comment: Thanks, dtxt_days works and populates with the number given if I do something like `this.mc_counter.dtxt_days.text = 38;`

Comment: edit your tags. This is not javascript. console log doesn't work here. Try trace().
Edit: wait. this is createjs. I never done a thing with this.

Comment: This is not flash AS3, it's flash canvas for HTML5 - console log works fine and is outputting in chrome console. Oh I see your edit. Yes, but createjs docs don't really help o.O :(

Comment: I think the problem is just a javascript problem, it's just the line `this.mc_counter.dtxt_days.text = days;` and the 3 below that are creating a problem.

Comment: I see you write AS2. Am i correct? Are you sure create js supports AS2. I did not write AS3 long time.

Comment: No this is javascript, not as2.

Comment: This is really weird for me. Sorry. I can't help with my current knowledge.

Comment: Hey no problem, thanks for taking a look !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning the variables in the lines of code with errors to something that doesn't exist.

```
this.days != days
```

Instead, make sure you're getting the properties you just assigned to `this`.

```
this.mc_counter.dtxt_days.text = this.days;
this.mc_counter.dtxt_hours.text = this.hours;
this.mc_counter.dtxt_mins.text = this.minutes;
this.mc_counter.dtxt_secs.text = this.seconds;
```

Additionally - `this` doesn't refer to what you think it does. Since `showRemaining` is a function, `this` in the code inside it actually refers to `showRemaining`. There's a couple ways to solve this. Here's arguably the simplest one:

```
var self = this;
function showRemaining() {
   self.days = ...
   self.mc_counter.dtxt_days.txt = ...
}
```

That simply stores a reference to the outer `this`. Alternatively, you can do the following:

```
timer = setInterval(showRemaining.call(this), 1000);
```

Which assigns the `this` inside `showRemaining` to the outer `this`.

Comment: Thanks. That's not the answer, it doesn't work. `this.mc_counter.dtxt_days.text` is not working inside the function for some reason. When I do `this.mc_counter.dtxt_days.text = "100";` my text box populates, when I do `this.days = 10;

function showRemaining() {

 this.mc_counter.dtxt_days.text = this.days;
}

showRemaining();' I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dtxt_days' of undefined` :(

Comment: Updated my answer @AgentZebra. That should fix it. :)